# Is there a term for a person who loves to adventure but thrives in routine?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, adjectives

Is there a word or term or phrase (in any language) that describes a person who has a lot of grand ideas for their life but doesn't actually do any of them? Something like a daydreamer, or a dreamer, or an uninhibited person, or a free-spirit?

Comment: "Is there a term for a person who loves to adventure but thrives in routine?" There shouldn't be. People who **talk the talk but don't walk the walk**, is a different question.

Answer (score 2):

[Mittyesque](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mittyesque), based on the fictional character Walter Mitty, who daydreamed of being an adventurer or hero.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you’re searching for is the adjective **Armchair**.

> **[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/armchair)**
>
> **Armchair** [as modifier] Lacking or not involving practical or direct experience of a particular subject or activity.*‘an armchair traveller’*

Some common usages for this are ‘Armchair Adventurer’ and ‘Armchair Enthusiast’. Both to indicate interest in a subject/activity without actually having experience or doing the thing.